# Error using basemaps in R, 'Access window out of range in RasterIO()'

Tags: r, mapping, gdal

I am new to mapping. I am trying to get a basemap of Virginia, but I keep running into an error (though the code technically runs). I am using the basemap_ggplot() function in the basemaps library.
How do I resolve these warnings and create a functional map? I am using esri and ua_topo_maps as the map_service / map_type, though any map of VA would work for me.

I ran the following code block

```
library(basemaps)
library(sf)
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(   
   ~Lat, ~Lon,  
   36.5,  -84,
   39.4,  -75)

df_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(df, coords=c("Lon", "Lat"), crs='EPSG: 4326', agr = "identity")
bbox <- sf::st_bbox(df_sf)

ex = st_transform(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(df_sf)), crs = 'EPSG: 4326')

set_defaults(map_service = "esri", map_type = "usa_topo_maps", map_res = 2)
bb <-  basemap_ggplot(ext=ex, verbose = F)
print(bb)
```

The error I recieve is :
Warning: Transforming 'ext' to Web Mercator (EPSG: 3857), since 'ext' has a different CRS. The CRS of the returned basemap will be Web Mercator, which is the default CRS used by the supported tile services.
Warning messages:
1: C:/Users/ejp42531/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWsjeeP/basemaps/esri_usa_topo_maps_68_98.png: Access window out of range in RasterIO().  Requested (0,0) of size 896x512 on raster of 256x256. (GDAL error 5)
2: C:/Users/ejp42531/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWsjeeP/basemaps/esri_usa_topo_maps_69_98.png: Access window out of range in RasterIO().  Requested (0,0) of size 896x512 on raster of 256x256. (GDAL error 5)

And so on up to 9. I attached the image of what the resulting map looks like. Large black patches cover areas and there is layers of shading I do not know how to remove.